# Pasar a JSON un array de PHP de una tabla mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

tengo un problema. Tengo un tabla de productos en mysql, al cual me conecto y llamo por medio de una consulta, pero aun no logro pasar el array de esa tabla generada por fetch_assoc(); a un JSON para poder trabajar con su objetos, asi poder capturar cada uno de los datos y mostrarlos con jquery en una tabla.

me gustaria poder tener los datos en consola para luego tomarlos con jquery en el success como respuesta y con ello mostrar con jquery toda la información

el tema es que no puedo tener el JSON en consola para ver cada unos de los objetos.

Codigo PHP

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');


$query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$resource = $conn->query($query);
$total = $resource->num_rows;

while($row = $resource->fetch_assoc();) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

 json_encode($array[]);
?>
```

Codigo JS

```
function listar_productos() {

$.ajax({
    url: 'productos.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (respuesta) {

        // Guardamos la respuesta de la URL en una variable.
        console.log(respuesta);
        var productos = (respuesta);

        //creamos una variable que jquery llame a un id con tbody dentro.
        var tabla_productos = $('#contenido tbody');
        // remueve los nodos hijos de un elemento seleccionado
        tabla_productos.empty();

        // $.each es un bucle para recorrer objetos,  que dentro de ella va una funcion 
        // index entrega la posición de dicho elemento en el bucle
        $.each(productos, function (index, producto) {

            // fila
            var fila = $('<tr></tr>');
            // ID
            var columna_id = $('<th></th>').text(producto.id);
            fila.append(columna_id);
            // IMG
            var columna_imagen = $('<th></th>')
            var imagen = $('<img />').attr('src',producto.imagen).addClass('img-fluid w-50');
            columna_imagen.append(imagen);
            fila.append(columna_imagen);
            // Nombre
            var columna_name = $('<td></td>').text(producto.nombre);
            fila.append(columna_name);
            // Descripcion
            var columna_description = $('<td></td>').text(producto.descripcion);
            fila.append(columna_description);

            tabla_productos.append(fila)

            // Añade botón de editar al DOM
            var columna_funciones = $('<td></td>')
            var boton_editar = $('<button><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Editar</button>')
            boton_editar.addClass('btn btn-primary mr-2 editar')
            boton_editar.attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
            boton_editar.attr('data-target', '#modalEditar')
            boton_editar.attr('data-identificador', producto.id)
            boton_editar.attr('data-imagen',producto.imagen)
            boton_editar.attr('data-nombre',producto.nombre)
            boton_editar.attr('data-descripcion',producto.descripcion)

            columna_funciones.append(boton_editar)

            // Añade botón de eliminar al DOM
            var boton_eliminar = $('<button><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"> Eliminar</i></button>')
            boton_eliminar.addClass('btn btn-danger borrar')
            boton_eliminar.attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
            boton_eliminar.attr('data-target', '#modalEliminar')
            boton_eliminar.attr('data-identificador', producto.id)
            boton_eliminar.attr('data-nombre', producto.nombre)
            
            columna_funciones.append(boton_eliminar)

            fila.append(columna_funciones)
            
        });

        
    },
    // Muestra un error en pantalla si es que no se pueden obtener los datos de la URL.
    error: function (error) {
        console.error("Sin respuesta del servidor");
    },

    
});
```

}

Comment: Esto `json_encode($array[])` que salida te da?

Comment: Aquí al final tienes un punto y coma que no va $resource->fetch_assoc();) sin contar que por ejemplo te falta hacerle echo al string que retorna tu PHP

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores en dos líneas : un `;` al final de los parámetros del while y no estas imprimiendo el json, además, no debes usar  [] en esa parte, ya no estás llenando el array que es para lo que sirve [].

Además, deberías controlar errores para devolver al cliente una respuesta siempre, también cuando no haya filas.

Por ejemplo:

```
include_once('conexion.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$resource = $conn->query($query);
$total = $resource->num_rows;
$array=array();

if($total>0) {
    while($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
 } else {
     $array['fail']='No se encontraron filas';
 }

 echo json_encode($array);
```

Si no hay filas, la respuesta tendrá una clave `fail`. En el `success` puedes preguntar por ella, para actuar en consecuencia (mostrar un mensaje o lo que sea).

Comment: Pero el Ajax me sigue indicando que no tiene respuesta en el servidor, como mensaje de error ($.ajax....). no logro el JSON en consola para trabajar con los objetos.

Comment: @GhostCoder ¿cuál es el error?

Comment: error: function (error) {
            console.error("Sin respuesta del servidor");
        },

Comment: Eso me responde el codigo JS que estaba arriba.

Comment: @GhostCoder revisa que no haya errores en tu código PHP. El mensaje indica que hay un error a nivel de servidor y eso puede ocurrir hasta con que olvides terminar una línea con `;`